# Extracting from multiple text flies, appending results

Tags: python, function, append, extract, glob

I wrote a function to extract from text files with regex. The function returns each variable. I have many files and want to iterate over the files and append the results. Each variable is a list; I will combine these to create a DF. This also works.

I understand there is glob, but having trouble implementing. I've used it for directory / file lists in the past. I've been searching / reading a lot but clearly missing something obvious.

I wrote the function and have used glob to list file names before. I know of list.append, but unsure how to combine with glob (or similar).

**How can I iterate over the files, call this function and append the results after each iteration?**

TEXT:

```
A bunch of sentences
CUSTOMER: 78787
amount (500 dollars)
A bunch of sentences
```

CODE

```
def find(customer, amount):    
    with open(r"file.txt",'r') as myfile:
        text = myfile.read() 

    customer = re.findall(r"^CUSTOMER:[\s](.*)\d+", text) 
    amount = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', text)

    return customer, amount
```

The function works, but only for the one file currently read.

Comment: What is the question? How to call a function in a loop? OR how to iterate over files in a directory? Or something else?

Comment: @JacobIRR No; I just edited to remove the single quote.

Comment: @wwii Sorry for the confusion; my question is: How can I call that function on each file I have. I know I need to call in the list of files (presumably with glob), loop over them, apply the function and keep the data after each iteration and append.

Comment: Can you give sample file names that you want to operate on?

Comment: customer_info_1.txt, customer_info_2.txt, customer_info_3.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the list of files generated with your function. Also, there is no point in passing in `customer` or `amount`. They are simply created at runtime of your `find` function and persist after they are returned.

You can use `pathlib.Path`'s `glob` method. 
Here goes:

```py
from pathlib import Path

def find(file_name):    
    with open(file_name,'r') as f:
        text = f.read() 

    customer = re.findall(r"^CUSTOMER:[\s](.*)\d+", text) 
    amount = re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', text)

    return customer, amount

file_dir = Path("path_to_directory_containing_files") # CHANGE THIS
all_files = file_dir.glob("*.txt") # this should be whatever pattern that matches all the input files
results = [find(f) for f in all_files]
```